# floating horizontal bar for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html table that is very tall. The web page has to be scrolled vertically to reach the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the table. It would be nice if I could float the horizontal scroll bar for the table at the bottom of the browser window.Can such a thing be done?Is der any plugin available for it?

```
JS Fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/RurTZ/1/
```

Comment: Please don't try and circumvent the requirement to include code when adding a link to jsfiddle. It's there for a reason. If jsfiddle goes down, your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution with the demo table from Maddy (I hope you don't mind):

Use a `range input` and bind a `handler` for the `input event` to it. Then you can use jquery's `.scrollLeft` to scroll your `table`.

This way you can position the scroll bar wherever you want it, and even style it the way you want.

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zstejf6a/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but, I suggest you to use the CSS property

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to your table.. This should do the work.

Comment: This will not fix the horizontal scroll bar to the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be its helpful for you:-

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/RurTZ/14/)</kbd>

```
<div style="width: 300px;overflow: scroll;height:400px">
    <div>
        <div style="height: 100%;">
            <table class='sample'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript, you can access the documents height using document.height.

Then calculate your elements css positioning accordingly, set the height of the tables parent div to document.height - 100px etc.

NOTE: this will require proper testing as it will not work for many scenarios. But if you have a simple page and understand the basics of page layout and css positioning it could do the trick.

Since you asked for a plug-in or something, try [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) , this would be easy to implement and can handle alot of customizations etc. , browser the docs. However if your requirements remain simple, this may be overkill.